# Insertar un gráfico

Tags: script, gráficas

Como puedo insertar una gráfica creada en hoja de cálculo de Google en una plantilla de documentos de Google mediante scripts

---

Tengo definidas las pestañas de la Hoja:

```
var vector=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() /* vector de pestañas */
var hojas0 =vector.getSheets()[0] /* 1 pestaña */
var hojas1 =vector.getSheets()[1] /* 2 pestña */
var hojas2 =vector.getSheets()[2] /* 3 pestaña */
var hojas3 =vector.getSheets()[3] /* 4 pestaña */
var hojas4 =vector.getSheets()[4] /* pestaña de la gráfica*/
var hojas5 =vector.getSheets()[5] /* 6 pestaña*/
var hojas6 =vector.getSheets()[6] /* 7 pestaña */
var hojas7 =vector.getSheets()[7] /* 8 pestaña */
var hojas8 =vector.getSheets()[8] /* 9 pestaña */
```

Dentro de hojas4 tengo la gráfica:

Como accedo a la gráfica.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya tienes creada el documento y el grafico... Lo primero que debes hacer es habilitar el servicio de Google Sheets en la consola de scripts de Google App Script; luego debes abrir la consola de scripts, hacer clic en **Archivo**, seleccionar

> Habilitar servicios de terceros

En el menú desplegable y buscar **Google Sheets** en la nueva ventana que aparece. Una vez seleccionado, haz clic en **Habilitar** para habilitar el servicio.

```
// Reemplaza SPREADSHEET_URL con la URL de la hoja de cálculo que contiene la gráfica
// Reemplaza CHART_ID con el ID de la gráfica
// Reemplaza DOCUMENT_ID con el ID del documento
function insertChart() {
  var spreadsheetUrl = 'SPREADSHEET_URL';
  var chartId = 'CHART_ID';
  var documentId = 'DOCUMENT_ID';

  var chart = Sheets.Charts.get(spreadsheetUrl, chartId);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
  doc.insertChart(chart);
}
```

Comment: Tengo definidas las pestañas de la hoja de la hoja activa. Quiero copiar la gráfica que he generado con una tabla de valores que están en la misma pestaña 4 ("var hojas4 = vector.getSheets()[4]") en un documento que tengo con más campos de las otras pestañas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar algo como esto:

```
var charts = hojas4.getCharts();
var chart = charts[0];
```

Como tienes tienes acceso a la gráfica, puedes insertarla en tu documento de Google utilizando la función insertChart() de la clase DocumentApp, como se muestra en el código que proporcioné en mi primer mensaje. Simplemente tendrás que reemplazar DOCUMENT_ID con el ID del documento en el que quieres insertar la gráfica y chart con la variable que contiene la gráfica que deseas insertar.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!